# FileInputStream with created class import

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to splice files to classes, i have file VKFile.java:

```
public class VKFile extends Activity {
public VKFile() {
    Log.d("BTCR", "Object VKFile created.");
}
public String read(String FILENAME){
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    String line;
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result = new JSONArray(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("BTCR", "file.read, respond: "+result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Then i create object in AuthorizedActivity.java - onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.authorized_main);
    VKFile vkFile = new VKFile();
    vkFile.read("myfile");
}
```

After run this code i have app crash with this logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.mirgorod.btcrussia/id.mirgorod.btcrussia.AuthorizedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:175)
at id.mirgorod.btcrussia.VKFile.read(VKFile.java:25)
at id.mirgorod.btcrussia.AuthorizedActivity.onCreate(AuthorizedActivity.java:129)
```

Why this happening? Same code work perfect if i place class in AuthorizedActivity.java, but give me error if i try to put code in other class.

Comment: Dont call methods from other Activity classes unless they are static, it now you are creating more activites - they are heavy. Instead delete `extends Activity` or do `public static String read(Context context , String FILENAME){` and `inputStream = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);`. Then use it by `VkFile.read(AuthorizedActivity.this,"myfile");`

Comment: Read the error message: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

Toumash, thank for this!

Dont call methods from other Activity classes unless they are static, it now you are creating more activites - they are heavy. Instead delete extends Activity or do

```
public static String read(Context context , String FILENAME){
```

and

```
inputStream = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

Then use it by

```
VkFile.read(AuthorizedActivity.this,"myfile");
```